# Is this Git workflow acceptable?

Tags: git

Git Workflow

- Developer 1 (France) - Local Machine - Local Project Files - Local repository
- Developer 2 (Brasil) - Local Machine - Local Project Files - Local repository
- Github - Remote Machine - No Files At all - Remote Repository

Both developers, push and pull, by connecting the *LOCAL Repository* with the *REMOTE repository on github*.

Once we want to upload the project, we do so from ONE of the local machines, trough ftp, to our shared host.

Could this be an acceptable work-flow ?

Thanks in advance.

**Update**

So, and if I understood well alexcepoi comment, we can accomplish the above by doing:


Git Workflow - v2 :)

- Developer 1 (France) - Local Machine - Local Project Files - Local repository
- Developer 2 (Brasil) - Local Machine - Local Project Files - Local repository
- Github - Remote Machine - No Files At all - Remote Repository
- Local Machine - No Files at all - Local Repository (from Pull Github Remote Repository).

I'm new, and I'm sure I will mess up on something IF I have, on the same machine, two git clients. (if this is possible), one for development. Another for "pull from github" and upload using ftp.

Should we have another machine, and then we ssh to it somehow? So that we can perfectly realise that we ARE NOT messing around?

What do you think?

Thanks a lot again, and sorry for all those dummy questions. Really. :)

Comment: You may want to use something like [Fabric](http://fabfile.org) or [Capistrano](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/wiki) for your deployment.

Comment: I'm totally new here, and I'm not sure how/why another tool will help me out here. (Despite reading the introdutory informations on both sites provided) - care to explain a little bit for, for dummies like myself. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Fabric and Capistrano are 2 deployment frameworks (in python and ruby) which are used for deploying projects. They use ssh to accomplish this and are mainly used for a lot of deployment servers. They can also support many roles (a server for database, a webserver, etc..). Setting them up is a rather complex task...

Comment: I realise that complexity. I have enough troubles already. I must leave that for another moon. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see why not. You can replace the ftp with another git client that tracks the master branch if you want...

Comment: Sorry, not getting. Replacing the ftp with a master branch? Not following... I'm quite new to all this. I've never used git before, and I'm on that phase were I need to prepare a workflow. Care to provide more details about what you are saying please? :)

Comment: The way one usually does this: client1 has a branch, client2 has a branch, both commit to their respective branches. There is also a master branch which is mainly used for production. Both clients can "merge" to the master branch. Now you can replace the production server with another local repository which pulls from the master branch from github... Hope this makes any sense

Comment: Just updated my question, hopping that I understood your suggestion. :) Care to have a look and edit your answer accordingly. Thanks again.

Comment: All local repositories (so every machine but the remote one from github) push and pull (i.e. 'track') from the remote repository. I was suggesting you give up using ftp and instead ssh to the production machine (last machine on your list) and do a git pull, which would update all your sources from the remote.

Answer (score 1):

I should use something like [Capistrano](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano) for the deployment. But if you deside to not do that, than you can use ftp also ofcourse. Just be sure to pull first before deploying :)

Comment: Capistrano is just not a choice right now. It's to complicated to get it working for such a newbie like me. So was git a while go, and here I am, trying to use it. So, I will get back to it, when I feel comfortable enough. :)

Comment: I've just found a book that helps me on deploying capistrano on a Zend project. Line by line. In that case, and imagining that Capistrano is implemented, will I still need github? Where will the master branch be? Can you edit your answer by using the same workflow schema that I've used on my question? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Yes you can still use github. In capistrano you can enter the server details for github and it will get the data from github!

Comment: Check here for more information! http://railscasts.com/episodes/133-capistrano-tasks

Comment: So, the only thing I need is, indeed, a shared host that allows me to deploy trough capistrano commands?